# Should country specific "Constitution" tags redirect to "constitution"?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is currently a [us-constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) and a more generic [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution).  [This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/871/why-does-the-united-states-have-a-federal-department-of-education) on the Constitutionality of the United States Department of Education was originally tagged with [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution).  I updated the constitution tag to us-constitution.

Should we aggregate all country specific constitution tags to [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) and add a second tag indicating the country in question, or continue using country specific constitution tags?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd be inclined to go the other way.

If a question were tagged both [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) it's clear to me that the question is related to *both* the USA and the constitution. It is likely to be interesting to those with interests in the USA and constitutional questions in general.

If a question were tagged [us-constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) then the [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag essentially becomes redundant for that question. If someone was interested in constitutional questions, they are likely to miss many that belong to entities that only just have their first questions being asked.

Lastly, users are more likely to discover the [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) tag than the specific [entity-constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-constitution), so it feels like we're making a lot of work for ourselves.

Answer (score -2):

I personally think that it makes sense to have both a [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) and [us-constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) even though we have separate country tags.  In my view the [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) tag should be reserved for questions about the theory, history or operation of constitutional governments generally, while specific questions asking for legality of some event/thing against a specific constitution should be written against the country specific tag.