# Should 'us-constitution' be burninated?

Tags: discussion, tags

Of [eighteen](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) questions tagged [us-constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution), only [one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution+-united-states+-constitution) has neither [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) nor [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution) as well. That seems definitively redundant to me.

Should it be burninated?

If so, I'd be happy to do the limited retagging required myself ...

**Related:** [Should country specific “Constitution” tags redirect to “constitution”?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/235/97)

Comment: On the basis that silence = consent, I've now gone ahead and retagged all [tag:us-constitution] questions with [tag:united-states] and [tag:constitution].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that they should probably be retagged [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [constitution](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitution)